Как правильно указывать функции в качестве аргументов
Использую в функции в качестве аргументов функции импортированные из других файлов
from datetime_v4 import t
from datetime_v4 import name
from log import l

l(name(), t())

функция l()
import logging

dirlog = r'C:\Test\log.txt'

def l(b,a):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(dirlog)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter())
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.info('Скрипт {} начал работу'.format(b))

    try:
        a
    except ValueError as v:
        logger.error(v)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as k:
        logger.error('Исполнение прервано вручную')

    logger.info('Скрипт завершил работу'+'\n')


if __name__=="__l__":
    l(b,a)    



Если прописываю l(name(),t()) то отрабатывает только раздел с try. Если прописываю l(name(),t) то запись в файл происходит но не отрабатывает раздел с try
Подскажите как правильно прописать чтобы функция l полностью отрабатывала

Передавать правильно l(name(),t), но внутри нужно вызывать функцию, со скобками: a()
